# Migrating from generators to async / await

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I am having an issue migrating below two functions from generators to async / await.
When I await the `endPoints` inside `send()`, I get the promise return value from `fixedPublisher()` as undefined.
Am I missing anything below ?

Generators:

```
export function* fixedPublisher(endpoints: any): any {
  while (endpoints !== undefined) {
    yield co(function* send(): any {
      return endpoints;
    });
  }
}

function* send(publisher: any, rnd: any): any {
  const p = publisher.next();
  if (p.done) {
    throw new Error('publisher is done');
  }
  const endpoints = yield p.value;
  if (!endpoints || endpoints.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('publisher did not return endpoints');
  }
  const m = Math.max(endpoints.length - 1, 0);

  return endpoints[rnd.integer(0, m)];
}
```

Async / Await:

```
export async function fixedPublisher(endpoints: any): Promise<any> {
    return await co(endpoints);
}

function* send(publisher: any, rnd: any): any {
  const endpoints =  await (publisher);
  if (!endpoints || endpoints.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('publisher did not return endpoints');
  }
  const m = Math.max(endpoints.length - 1, 0);
  return endpoints[rnd.integer(0, m)];
}
```

Comment: A promise can only return once, I don't think you can `await` for more than one execution of the function you're awaiting(I don't know what the `co` definition is here). But, if that checks out, functions where you use `await` must be declared with the `async` keyword as well, meaning that your `send` function also needs an `async` in declaration(and also have to return a promise).

Comment: You don't need `co` anymore when moving to async/await. They are doing the same job. I would guess `return await co(endpoints)` is your problem, because `co()` does not return a promise. Also, is `publisher` a promise? That must be converted to return a promise.